# Fix duplicate column name error on an SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join

My SQL assignment uses the IMDB database. I want to save joins as a new table. It always raises an error on MySQL Workbench.

```sql
DROP TABLE dir_movie_join;
CREATE TABLE dir_movie_join 
(
    SELECT t1.*, t2.*
    FROM directors t1
    LEFT JOIN movies t2 ON t1.index = t2.index
);
```

> `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'index'`

How do I navigate this?

Comment: thanks.  Your new table `dir_movie_join` was supposed to be all rows from directors and movies but since both have an `index` column, `dir_movie_join` can't have both tables' columns together as named in the source tables.  Is there some reason you're trying to `CREATE TABLE` here in the first place?

Comment: you can `CREATE TABLE ` from any select that returns *unique* columns regardless of what joins it contains.  Since your JOIN includes `index` from both `movies` and `directors` the resulting columns are not *uniquely* named and thus can't be used to CREATE TABLE.

Comment: "to exploit the join further" you dont' want to `create table` for this purpose anyway.  That duplicates all the data in both source tables at time of query and removes all mysql keys that might be on the data. If you really want a table-like thing that reflects that query's results, use a view.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: This is because both the directors and movies tables have a column named index.Instead of using t1.* and t2.*.Use alias for t1.index as dir_index and t2.index as movie.index and use left join accordingly.Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't put answers or notice of answers or that you found one in question posts. Questions are forever for other searchers/readers regardless of whether you ever find an answer. I rolled back your edit. You can post your own answer. You can edit your post to try to improve it. (But issues pinned down from this question will be unhelpful duplicates.) If one answer helped you most please click on the check mark indicating that.

Comment: that was my own answer using the suggestions received.

Comment: I don't undestand what the point of your comment is. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.*`, specify just the necessary columns.  In doing so, you must decide which "index" to include in the new table.  If the values are always the same, pick either and leave the other behind.  If they are different, give one of them a different name via aliasing.

`CREATE TABLE` is usually done only when you start a project.  It is not a daily task.

A `SELECT` to fetch data from several tables can include a `JOIN`; but that is normally done during the `SELECT`, without creating any new tables.